# Unable to determine if Radio Button is checked

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, radio-button

I have attempted to use the document.getElementById method to determine if a radio button within a ListView has been checked. The result of that check is a value of 'undetermined' although I have actually checked one of the radio buttons. I am doing this in a loop with the ID appending the index of the loop to the ID name.

The code that pertains to this issue follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function AllPickEmGamesSelected(visible)
{
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<16; i++) 
    {
        var HomeTeamVerif = document.getElementById("FeaturedContent_ListViewPickEm_RadioButtonHome_" + i).Checked;
        var AwayTeamVerif = document.getElementById("FeaturedContent_ListViewPickEm_RadioButtonAway_" + i).Checked;
        if (!HomeTeamVerif & !AwayTeamVerif)
        {
            visible = true;         
        }
    }
}

:
:
:
```

ASPX file:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewPickEm" runat="server">
<AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <tr style="color: white; background-color: forestgreen; border: groove; width: 100%;">
        <td style="float:left;">
            <asp:Label ID="DateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date") %>' />
        </td>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="GameID" Value=<%# Eval("GameID") %> runat="server" />
         <td>
            <asp:Label ID="HomeTeamNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HomeTeamName") %>'  />
         </td>
         <td>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HomeID" Value=<%# Eval("HomeTeamID") %> runat="server" />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonHome" Checked="false" runat="server" GroupName="GameChoice" />
         </td>
         <td>
            <asp:Label ID="AwayTeamNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AwayTeamName") %>' />
         </td>
         <td>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="AwayID" Value=<%# Eval("AwayTeamID") %> runat="server" />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonAway" Checked="false" runat="server" GroupName="GameChoice" />
         </td>
     </tr>
 </AlternatingItemTemplate>
 <EmptyDataTemplate>
     <table id="Table1" runat="server" style="">
         <tr>
             <td>No data was returned.</td>
         </tr>
     </table>
 </EmptyDataTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
     <tr style="color: white; background-color: darkgreen; border: groove; width:100%;">
         <td style="float:left;">
             <asp:Label ID="DateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date") %>' />
         </td>
             <asp:HiddenField ID="GameID" Value=<%# Eval("GameID") %> runat="server" />
         <td>
             <asp:Label ID="HomeTeamNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HomeTeamName") %>' />
         </td>
         <td>
             <asp:HiddenField ID="HomeID" Value=<%# Eval("HomeTeamID") %> runat="server" />
             <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonHome" Checked="false" runat="server" GroupName="GameChoice" />
         </td>
         <td>
             <asp:Label ID="AwayTeamNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AwayTeamName") %>' />
         </td>
         <td>
             <asp:HiddenField ID="AwayID" Value=<%# Eval("AwayTeamID") %> runat="server" />
             <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonAway" Checked="false" runat="server" GroupName="GameChoice" />
         </td>
     </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <LayoutTemplate>
     <table id="Table2" runat="server">
         <tr>
             <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                 <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                     <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                         <th id="Th1" runat="server">Date</th>
                         <th style="float: right;" id="Th2" runat="server">Home Team</th>
                         <th id="Th3" runat="server"></th>
                         <th style="float:right;" id="Th4" runat="server">Away Team</th>
                         <th id="Th5" runat="server"></th>
                     </tr>
                     <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                     </tr>
                 </table>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="Tr2" runat="server">
             <td id="Td2" runat="server" style=""></td>
         </tr>
     </table>
 </LayoutTemplate>
 <SelectedItemTemplate>
     <tr>
         <td style="float:left;">
             <asp:Label ID="DateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date") %>' />
         </td>
             <asp:HiddenField ID="GameID" Value=<%# Eval("GameID") %> runat="server" />
         <td>
             <asp:Label ID="HomeTeamNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HomeTeamName") %>' />
         </td>
         <td>
             <asp:HiddenField ID="HomeIDvalue" Value=<%# Eval("HomeTeamID") %> runat="server" />
             <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonHome" Checked="false" runat="server"  />
         </td>
         <td>
             <asp:Label ID="AwayTeamNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AwayTeamName") %>' />
         </td>
         <td>
             <asp:HiddenField ID="AwayIDvalue" Value=<%# Eval("AwayTeamID") %> runat="server" />
                 <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonAway" Checked="false" runat="server" />
         </td>
     </tr>
 </SelectedItemTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
```

c# file:

```
protected void onPickEmSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //        Will ensure deadline time has not passed
    string dateTime = "08/25/2016 13:00:00.00";
    DateTime CutoffDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime);
    DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;
    if (localDate > CutoffDate)
    {
        // if deadline has passed, will send error message
        Overdue.Visible = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        //        Will ensure all games were picked
        //            else send an error message back
        Boolean visible = false;
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript((Page)this, base.GetType(), "AllPickEmGamesSelected" + DateTime.Now,
                                                     string.Format("AllPickEmGamesSelected('{0}');", visible), true);
        NotAllPicked.Visible = visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: C and C# are different languages, and have different tags.  Please add the tag C# and remove the C tag.  Anyways, you are more likely to attract people with the knowledge to answer your question if you have the right tags. :-)

Comment: Thanks. Inadvertent typo, but valuable catch.

Answer (score 1):

The way you fix this problem is only a small typo. Since JavaScript is a case-sensitive language, you need to change `Checked` to `checked`. So, your final JS code will be:

```
    function AllPickEmGamesSelected(visible)
{
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<16; i++) 
    {
        var HomeTeamVerif = document.getElementById("FeaturedContent_ListViewPickEm_RadioButtonHome_" + i).checked;
        var AwayTeamVerif = document.getElementById("FeaturedContent_ListViewPickEm_RadioButtonAway_" + i).checked;
        if (!HomeTeamVerif & !AwayTeamVerif)
        {
            visible = true;         
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry, but I didn't check this code. ;)

Comment: That got me further down the road as I found the value changed from being undefined to false. Now, the issue is that one of the buttons was actually clicked on. So, I'm trying to determine if the value actually changed when I clicked the submit button. That code is just below the previous aspx code, and it is as follows:

Comment: <!-- 
        Submit Button
    --->


                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="PickEmGames" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FollowingHSFootballConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="GetWeeklyGames" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="onPickEmSubmit" Height="30px" style="margin-left: 0px" Width="100px" />

Comment: @MDDeVane you can find this though a quick google search. It seems like that you want to submit a form, so you should search up "custom form validation html". I don't know much about aspx, so I've done my best on how I can lead you to the answer. :) Good luck!